# Pass variable from PHP to Powershell script

Tags: php, powershell, exec

I am trying to pass a variable from PHP to a powershell script.

My PHP code is :

```
shell_exec("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -InputFormat none -file test.ps1 '$txt' < NUL ");
```

And I am trying to capture it in powershell using :

```
param (
  [string]$txt
)

Add-Content "test.txt" $txt
```

The $txt is a string variable as I can write it in a txt file from PHP. I do not know exactly where I am wrong as the powershell is executed.

Comment: What's the problem? Is `test.txt` not getting created?

Comment: The text.txt is created, but empty. No $txt variable value is parsed.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-inputformat-text--xml) the `-InputFormat` parameter supports 'Text' or 'XML'. You give it 'none'. Try changing that to `Text`. And shouldn't `< NUL` be `> $null` ??

Comment: @mklement0 Sorry, I did not get the chance to check your solution until now. Many thanks, it did fix my problem.

Comment: No worries; glad to hear it worked; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
shell_exec("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -file test.ps1 \"$txt\"");
```

<sup>Note: If the value of `$txt` had embedded `"` chars., they'd need to be escaped.</sup>

- The PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) doesn't recognize `'...'` quoting when passing arguments to a script file executed via `-File`; use `"..."`.

  - Your attempt with `'$txt'` shouldn't have resulted in an *empty* file, but it would have included the `'` chars. *as part of the argument*; if `$txt` happens to contain spaces, each space-separated word would have become a *separate argument*, with the first starting with `'` and the last ending in `'`
- Since you're not providing input via stdin, there is no need for `-inputFormat` and `< NUL`